# Multiple $regex using $and in MongoDB

Tags: sql, regex, mongodb

I have some collection with the next records:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b18fb2a21351b2bb29dfc7"),
    "title" : "aaa"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b18fd0d17d7f69e078f7b7"),
    "title" : "bbb"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b18fd3d17d7f69e078f7b8"),
    "title" : "ccc"
}
```

Next query gives as a result 1 records (with title="aaa") as we expected:

```
db.test.find({
     {title:{$regex:'aaa'}}
})
```

But when we use complex condition for $and we got something unexpected:

```
db.test.find({
    $and: [
        {title:{$regex:'aaa'}},
        {title:{$regex:'bbb'}}
    ]
})
```

I need query exactly in this case because I'm going to use selection with stop-words, for example:

```
db.test.find({
    $and: [
        {title:{$regex:'aaa'}},
        {title:{$regex:'bbb'}},
        {title:{$not:/bbb/i}},
    ]
})
```

Using query that above, I expecting only one field in result (with title="aaa").

I have idea how to solve this issue using aggregate, but I hope there is another way how to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Simply build proper regex

```
pattern "/A AND B/"
pattern "/NOT (NOT A OR NOT B)/"
```

Regex:

```
"/^(^A|^B)/"
```

Or this one

```
/(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)/
```

Comment: I believe that using regexs like these I will have troubles with perfomance. Also, another similar way - use $where. But if I will have more than 10kk records in table, then time for executing that query will goes to lightly infinity..

Answer (score 1):

Well, tested using another data and got expected result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b18fb2a21351b2bb29dfc7"),
    "title" : "aaa"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b18fd0d17d7f69e078f7b7"),
    "title" : "bbb"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b18fd3d17d7f69e078f7b8"),
    "title" : "ccc"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b19606d17d7f69e078f7b9"),
    "title" : "aaa test"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b19624d17d7f69e078f7ba"),
    "title" : "aaa test wel"
}
```

Query:

```
db.test.find({
    $and: [
        {title:{$regex:'aa'}},
        {title:{$regex:'t'}},
        {title:{$not:/wel/}}
    ]
})
```

Response:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b19606d17d7f69e078f7b9"),
    "title" : "aaa test"
}
```

Perhaps, that issue reproducing only when title and conditions contains cyrillic symbols. Going to to reproduce it now..