# Is there a way to use multiple regex in an $and operator in an aggregate query?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I'm searching, inside a database which has a collection named Inventaire, in which there is an attribute Libelle, inventories that does not contain a the words 'screen', 'unite', 'station' nor 'disc' in it

I tried the code below

```
Inventaire.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        Nomenclature : { $nin : [null]},
        $and :[
            {
                Libelle : {$not : {$regex: '.*unité.*',$options: 'ig'}},
                Libelle : {$not : {$regex: '.*écran.*',$options: 'ig'}},    
                Libelle : {$not : {$regex: '.*ecran.*',$options: 'ig'}},
                Libelle : {$not : {$regex: '.*station.*',$options:'ig'}},
                Libelle : {$not : {$regex: '.*disque.*',$options: 'ig'}},
            }
        ],
        Etat : 'En état'
    },
},
{
    $group:
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

])

expected results are like Documents which have Libelle like "ABCDEF"not like "ABecranCD" nor "XYdisque"

Comment: Use one, with a pattern like `(?:unité|[ée]cran|station|disque)`

Comment: You can check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657951/multiple-regex-using-and-in-mongodb